# How to determine the Ant version when using Ant inside Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

How can I determine the version of Ant coming with Eclipse?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5126889/1599699

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the About Eclipse -> Eclipse.org button -> Eclipse.org Plug-in Details you will see Apache Ant plugin with version information

[image]

Answer (score 26):

You can do so by typing the following command:

`ant -version`

Comment: Type this where?

Answer (score 18):

Inside your ant script the `ant.version` property holds the information, if you need it programatically.

Comment: `ant.version` contains something like this: `Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015`

Comment: However, there is Antversion task: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antversion.html to get the version in parseable format.

Answer (score 10):

Although TigrisCs answer will give you the installed Ant bundle version, this version is not neccessarily the version you're executing your Ant files against. The dialog where you find the Ant version that is used to execute Ant files you'll find under Window->Preferences->Ant->Runtime

[image: Ant runtime preferences]

HTH Tom