# How to check Ant version inside Ant script

Tags: java, ant

My ant script only works with version >=1.8. I want to check the version in the script, so that it displays error if a lesser version installed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5126301/829571

Comment: I want to do it in a automated fashion inside the script itself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ant has built-in property `ant.version`:

```
<project default="print-version">
    <target name="print-version">
        <echo>${ant.version}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Using the <antversion> task is the preferred way to check ant versions as of 1.7.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a code snip that may help:

```
<property name="version.required" value="1.8" />

<target name="version_check">
    <antversion property="version.running" />
    <fail message="FATAL ERROR:  The running Ant version, ${version.running}, is too old.">
        <condition>
            <not>
                <antversion atleast="${version.required}" />
            </not>
        </condition>
    </fail>
</target>

<target name="doit" depends="version_check">
    <echo level="info" message="The running version of ant, ${version.running}, is new enough" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 9):

No need to create a target, you can use [fail](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html)+[antversion](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antversion.html) at the beginning of your script :

```
<fail message="Ant 1.8+ required">
     <condition>
         <not><antversion atleast="1.8" /></not>
     </condition>
</fail>
```

Comment: This is the best answer here.

Answer (score 5):

Version 1.7 of ANT introduced a dedicated [antversion](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antversion.html) task.

This functionality is part of several [conditions](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) that can be checked by ANT.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following at the beginning of your build script:

```
<!-- Check Ant Version -->
<property name="ant.version.required"       value="1.9.8" />

<fail message="Ant version ${ant.version.required} or newer is required 
      (${ant.version} is installed)">
  <condition>
    <not><antversion atleast="${ant.version.required}" /></not>
  </condition>
</fail>
```

If the Ant version is lower than required, it will produce an error like this:

> Ant version 1.9.8 or newer is required (Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.7 compiled on April 9 2016 is installed)

Answer (score 0):

In terminal type, just execute:

```
ant -version
```