# Can I get ant to ignore attributes it doesn't understand?

Tags: ant, zip

Ant 1.9 behaves differently to Ant 1.8 and I need to be able to build with both for a transition period. I need to set the `zip64mode="never"` attribute in 1.9, but when used with 1.8 this reports `zip doesn't support the "zip64mode" attribute`.

Is there a way I can get ant to ignore attributes it doesn't understand? I thought that was how XML was supposed to work.

Comment: Please post question little more clearly

Comment: That might be clearer now, or not.

Comment: How much do you need zip64?  I'd keep it simple and upgrade to ant 1.9.1 when you can safely abandon 1.8.x

Comment: @Pandiyan Cool - simpler?

Comment: @thekbb I don't need zip64, hence disabling it, but I do need to be compatible with ant 1.9 as well as 1.8.

Comment: @Matt sorry i said now better

Answer (score 2):

First of all the following question outlines various methods to determine which version of ANT is running:

- [How to check Ant version inside Ant script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514222/how-to-check-ant-version-inside-ant-script/10522210#10522210)

You could try the following in order to get your build to support multiple versions of ANT

```
<antversion property="ant.1.9.or.higher" atleast="1.9"/>

<target name="task-with-zip64mode" if="ant.1.9.or.higher">
..
</target>

<target name="task-without-zip64mode" unless="ant.1.9.or.higher">
..
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found one workaround... it's rather a kludge though.

I can take advantage of default behaviour of the `jar` task which defaults to `zip64mode="never"`.

> [Zip task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html#zip64):
>   "never means no Zip64 extra fields will ever be written, this is the
>   behavior of Ant 1.8.x and earlier and **the default behavior of jar**, ear
>   and war starting with Ant 1.9.1."

It saves having to have two targets and check the version of ant running, but it's not nice.