# "Ant 1.9.4" throws Class not found: javac1.8

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, ant

I'm trying to use Apache Ant for Java development.
I did everything as written here:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheAnt/article.html
but my Eclipse said:
BUILD FAILED
Class not found: javac1.8

I googled, that this error is known to happen with Apache Ant versions less than 1.9.0 - which aren't compatible with Java 8, but I use Apache Ant 1.9.4.

Цhat could it be?

Comment: Check the version of ant you have installed in Eclipse .. About Eclipse -> Eclipse.org [button] -> Eclipse.org Plug-in Details look at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125987/how-to-determine-the-ant-version-when-using-ant-inside-eclipse